# Setup web dav with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, webdav

I m looking for setup WebDAV to my tomcat. I m new to this concept. I want which war file to be downloaded. how to set up wabdav in my tomcat. to do program with java

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat comes with a servlet that enables webdav. Add the following code to your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webdav</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.WebdavServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>readonly</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowSpecialPaths</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webdav</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webdav/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The content of your application can be accessed via:

```
http://localhost:8080/YOURAPPNAME/webdav.
```

Be sure to enable a security constraint for this servlet.

Comment: How to change the default directory ?.I want server fiels from my own path rather than toot